# How do jumping and dashing combos work?

Tags: robot-unicorn-attack-2

I've been playing Robot Unicorn Attack 2 on Android, and am quite confused by the jumping and dashing combos, and when I can use them. For example, with a standard robot unicorn:

<kbd>Jump</kbd> > <kbd>Jump</kbd> > <kbd>Jump</kbd> - I cannot jump anymore.

<kbd>Jump</kbd> > <kbd>Jump</kbd> > <kbd>Dash</kbd> > <kbd>Jump</kbd> > <kbd>Jump</kbd> - I get four jumps?

<kbd>Jump</kbd> > <kbd>Jump</kbd> > <kbd>Jump</kbd> > <kbd>Dash</kbd> > <kbd>Jump</kbd> > <kbd>Dash</kbd> > <kbd>Jump</kbd> > <kbd>Dash</kbd> > <kbd>Jump</kbd> - 6 Jumps!

<kbd>Jump</kbd> > <kbd>Dash</kbd> > <kbd>Dash</kbd> - And I'm done.

How do jump and dash combos work? I would like to stay in the air for as long as possible, as hoops multiply your score until you touch the ground.

Comment: I think your best bet to staying in the air long enough is the third combo. As for how they work, I believe the mechanism is that a dash counts as land so dash on the third jump and then maintain under two jumps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's quite simple: Every time you dash, your mid-air jump count gets reset.

There are some time restrictions that prevent you from dashing *constantly* - that is, you have to space out your dashes a bit - but there's no fixed limit to how many times you can dash in mid-air.

I'm not *completely* sure if it's possible to keep the jump going forever with the standard unicorn, or if the dash restrictions become too significant - but at the very least, you should find it easier to stay airborne if you buy one of the upgrades that gives you more mid-air jumps - since that gives you more time between dashes - but beyond that, it's just a matter of rhythm, and not letting go of jump before you reach the peak (since you start falling once you let go).

You can of course also buy some wings, and then you'll be able to stay airborne forever once you achieve flight speed - at the trade-off of removing mid-air jumps once you reach that speed, which means it takes longer to go from falling to rising.

Comment: You're 100% correct that there is a cooldown in the air. You can actually stay in the air indefinitely by doing 3+ jumps, dash, 3+ jumps, dash, etc.